# Input placeholder in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, inputtext, inputsecret

How to show a default value in apex:inputText so that when user enters the text box the value should disappear like it does in this HTML:

```
<input type="{!username}"  id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="{!password}"  id="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Can anyone please suggest how to implement this in Visualforce?

Comment: How can we change the color of placeholder text

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the recently introduced [pass through](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) attributes for this:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!username}" id="username" html-placeholder="Username"/>
<apex:inputSecret value="{!password}" id="password" html-placeholder="Password"/>
```

**PS** Cool page that lets you know [Can I use input placeholder attribute?](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)

Comment: I always forget about this feature.  Great answer