# PlaceHolder for Apex:inputTextArea

Tags: visualforce, html

Pass through attribute to display Ghost text is not working for Apex:inputTextArea. I mentioned docuType as 'Html-5.0' in apex page correctly.

Example :

```
<apex:inputTextarea value="{!test}" html-placeholder="test placeholder">
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
Sivarajan

Comment: This worked for me: <apex:inputTextarea html-placeholder="My Placeholder"/>

Comment: Thanks Ritika for ur quick reply. I tired and it's not working.

Comment: What is the exact code you are using for inputTextArea?

Comment: <apex:inputTextArea html-placeholder ="test placeholder">.

Comment: @sivarajanDhandapani What browser are you in ?

Comment: I tested in Chrome and IE

Comment: Is there any value in test variable? If so, it would display that value only. By the way, I didn't add docutype and it still worked for me.

Comment: go through this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/input-placeholder-in-visualforce-page?rq=1

Comment: @RitikaBhrgv ,  The problem is when I add richText = "True" attribute, the placeholder gets disappeared.   <apex:inputTextarea html-placeholder="test" richText="true"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you cannot show a placeholder in richtext area using html-placeholder. Not in the direct way, at least. Read on to find out why:

**Background:** Any tag used in a VF page is converted to basic HTML and then rendered into page. Events are then attached to individual fields to maintain the consistent behavior that all of us are fond of. html-placeholder attributes are added to the converted input tags as needed. For example, an apex:inputTextArea tag without richtext="true" gets converted to . By the default rule of html, placeholders can only be added to elements accepting input, which brings us to our richtext area field.

A rich-text area field is not rendered in salesforce like any other tag and handled entirely differently. If you do inspect element, you will notice that the textarea field is actually marked as display: none and not added to the page. Instead of this tag, there is a different markup added as an iframe which includes the additional functionality of a rich-text area. Now, whatever text we add in this is actually added as inner html of body contained inside the iframe. And, as you must have guessed by now, we cannot have placeholder defined for a body tag.

**DISCLAIMER:** This is just a tweak which I have experimented on to give placeholder behavior and cannot say for sure, if due to some Salesforce updates in future this stops being relevant, so consider opting for it at your own risk.

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!account.Name}"/>
    <apex:inputTextarea richText="true" value="{!account.RichTextField__c}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:form>

<script>
    $( window).load(function() {

        // Adding delay to allow richtext to be rendered on VF page
        setTimeout('addPlaceholder()', 2000);
   });

    // Function to add placeholder behavior to richtext area field
   function addPlaceholder() {

       // Adds placeholder on page load
        $('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").html('<p style="color: #e1e1e1;">Placeholder Text</p>');

        // Binds focusin event to Richtext and identify if no user defined text specified make it blank
        $('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").bind('focusin', function() {

            if($('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").html() == '<p style="color: #e1e1e1;">Placeholder Text</p>') {

                $('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").html('');
            }
        });

        // Binds focusout event to Richtext which appends placeholder again if no text is specified
        $('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").bind('focusout', function() {

            if($('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").html() == '') {

                $('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").html('<p style="color: #e1e1e1;">Placeholder Text</p>');
            }
        });
   }
</script>
```

The solution provided above, implicitly utilizes class name to get the element we need to control. Again, this yields the result we need, still there is distant possibility of Salesforce updating their architecture as they do not want us to tweak into their code (You may be surprised how frequently it happens). So, although a stable option for now, we cannot say for sure till when and if we can continue to use this.

Wish you the luck!

Comment: Thanks @ RitikaBhrgv, I found that iframe thing when I inspected text area earlier.

I agree your suggestions, in future Salesforce will definitely not allow to do this JS tweak. instead of displaying as placeholder, we planning to display as gray text below the label.

Thanks again your inputs.